# How to group an array by latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, arrays

So, I have the following array

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(30) "NAME 1"
    ["lat"]=>
    string(8) "1.326738"
    ["lng"]=>
    string(10) "102.746780"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(51) "NAME 2"
    ["lat"]=>
    string(8) "1.324738"
    ["lng"]=>
    string(10) "103.746780"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(29) "NAME 3"
    ["lat"]=>
    string(8) "1.326738"
    ["lng"]=>
    string(10) "102.746780"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "NAME 4"
    ["lat"]=>
    string(8) "1.324738"
    ["lng"]=>
    string(10) "103.746780"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(38) "NAME 5"
    ["lat"]=>
    string(8) "1.334755"
    ["lng"]=>
    string(10) "102.746780"
  }
}
```

How can I group the array by lat and lng field? Most of already answered question on SO just to group by one field. I want to output to become somewhat like this

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(38) "NAME 5"
    ["lat"]=>
    string(8) "1.334755"
    ["lng"]=>
    string(10) "102.746780"
  }
  ["group1"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(30) "NAME 1"
      ["lat"]=>
      string(8) "1.326738"
      ["lng"]=>
      string(10) "102.746780"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(29) "NAME 3"
      ["lat"]=>
      string(8) "1.326738"
      ["lng"]=>
      string(10) "102.746780"
    }
  }
  ["group2"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(29) "NAME 3"
      ["lat"]=>
      string(8) "1.324738"
      ["lng"]=>
      string(10) "103.746780"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(51) "NAME 2"
      ["lat"]=>
      string(8) "1.324738"
      ["lng"]=>
      string(10) "103.746780"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: in which way you want to create group??

Comment: I want to group them by EXACT same latitude AND longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by (lat, lng) with this function.

```
    groupBy('lat', 'lng', $data);

    function groupBy($keyA, $keyB, $data)
    {
        $results = [];

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $a = $value[$keyA];
            $b = $value[$keyB];

            $results[$a . '-' . $b][] = $value;
        }

        // If you want to set key is group1, group2, etc..
        $groupNo = 1;
        $temp = [];
        foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
            if ( count($value) > 1)
            {
                $temp['group'. $groupNo] = $value;

                $groupNo = $groupNo + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $temp[] = $value[0];
            }
        }
        $results = $temp;

        return $results;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $aEntry = array();
    $aEntry[ 'name' ] = 'NAME 1';
    $aEntry[ 'lat' ] = '1.326738';
    $aEntry[ 'lng' ] = '102.746780';

    $aEntry2 = array();
    $aEntry2[ 'name' ] = 'NAME 2';
    $aEntry2[ 'lat' ] = '1.326738';
    $aEntry2[ 'lng' ] = '102.746780';

    $aEntry3 = array();
    $aEntry3[ 'name' ] = 'NAME 2';
    $aEntry3[ 'lat' ] = '1.326738';
    $aEntry3[ 'lng' ] = '102.746780';

    $aEntry4 = array();
    $aEntry4[ 'name' ] = 'NAME 3';
    $aEntry4[ 'lat' ] = '1.326731';
    $aEntry4[ 'lng' ] = '102.746781';

    $aEntry5 = array();
    $aEntry5[ 'name' ] = 'NAME 4';
    $aEntry5[ 'lat' ] = '1.326731';
    $aEntry5[ 'lng' ] = '102.746781';

    $aEntry6 = array();
    $aEntry6[ 'name' ] = 'NAME 5';
    $aEntry6[ 'lat' ] = '1.326731';
    $aEntry6[ 'lng' ] = '102.746781';

    $aEntry7 = array();
    $aEntry7[ 'name' ] = 'NAME 5';
    $aEntry7[ 'lat' ] = '1.11111';
    $aEntry7[ 'lng' ] = '102.11111';

    $aData = array();
    $aData[] = $aEntry;
    $aData[] = $aEntry2;
    $aData[] = $aEntry3;
    $aData[] = $aEntry4;
    $aData[] = $aEntry5;
    $aData[] = $aEntry6;
    $aData[] = $aEntry7;


    $aFormatted = array();

    $iCountData = count( $aData );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountData; ++$i )
    {
        $vKeyToAppendTo = '';
        foreach( $aFormatted as $sKey => $aValues )
        {
            // Check if we already have the lat/lng combination stored.
            // Each formatted entry will share lat/lng
            if( ( $aValues[ 0 ][ 'lat' ] == $aData[ $i ][ 'lat' ] ) && ( $aValues[ 0 ][ 'lng' ] == $aData[ $i ][ 'lng' ] ) )
            {
                // Set the array key to append to.
                $vKeyToAppendTo = $sKey;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If we have a key match append.
        if( !empty( $vKeyToAppendTo ) )
        {
            $aFormatted[ $vKeyToAppendTo ][] = $aData[ $i ];
        }
        // Otherwise create the new lat/lng entry group.
        else
        {
            $aFormatted[ 'group' . $i ][] = $aData[ $i ];
        }
    }
    var_dump( $aFormatted );
?>
```